# HashMap memory allocation is not clear

Tags: java, android, hashmap

According to [android's developers site](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) it seems like the method

```
public V put (K key, V value)
```

will use the given value object as reference, while the method

```
public void putAll (Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map)
```

will copy each of the supplied map elements to a new value object.
The android source does not reveal the internals of each of these methods.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: I think putAll just uses put for each element in the map

Comment: btw, [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html) is the source for `java.util.HashMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`putAll` just iterate the entry set of the source Map and call `put (K key, V value)` for each k-v pair. Nothing special. So it behaves the same as calling `put` many times in a for loop.

Read the code below and then you'll be clear.

```
public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : m.entrySet())
            put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
```

Edited by the OP to complete the answer:
This code proves `put(key,value)` will not create a new object, but use the value argument, I just tested it and watch the variables in the debugger:

```
    Map<String, Rect> mymap = new HashMap<String, Rect>();
    Rect r1 = new Rect(0,120,200,155);
    mymap.put("corner", r1);
    r1.offset(20, 17);
    Rect r2 = mymap.get("corner");
```

r1 becomes (20,137,220,172) and so is the returned value r2, proving the reference is mantained.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as pass by reference in java:

http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

See this article for long discussion: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

When you call put, key and value are copied in. putAll is just to copy an entire map, it is like a convenience function to make it easier to copy maps.

Too see for yourself try editing the values of key and value after you call put, you will see that they don't change in the map they were copied into, only in the scope you change them in.

Basically the values are copied when passed into a function.

Comment: I tested it, as you suggested and you are wrong. Changing the value after `put` did change the map. Here is the short code if you want to try it yourself: `  Map<String, Rect> mymap = new HashMap<String, Rect>();
  Rect r1 = new Rect(0,120,200,155);
  mymap.put("corner", r1);
  r1.offset(20, 17);
  Rect r2 = mymap.get("corner");
` Notice that `r2` is returned equal to r1, which changed after `put`

Comment: look up the difference of shallow copy and deep copy champ

Comment: Not at all what I meant.

Comment: I get you, using the wording 'values' of 'value' is confusing too. You meant to change 'value' itself, not its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Copies all of the mappings from the specified map to 'this' map. These mappings will replace any mappings that 'this' map had for any of the keys currently in the specified map.
'this' is map object with which you are calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is incorrect. `putAll` will also copy only the references.

There would be even no clearly defined alternative, as we have in other languages like C++, where copy- and assignment-operators are very well definded. That's probably why the wording of the documentation seems a little bit unclear in this respect: It was very much worded with a typical java way of doing things in mind.